# Spring Integration HTTP inbound adapter method name?

Tags: http, spring-integration

Is it possible to map the method name to a header with a int-http:inbound-gateway? for example:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="requests" reply-channel="replies"
    supported-moethds="GET,PUT"
    path="/user">
    <int-http:header name="requestMethod" expression="#requestMethod"/>
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<!-- ... -->

<int:header-value-router input-channel="requests" header-name="requestMethod>
    <int:mapping value="GET" channel="getUserRequests"/>
    <int:mapping value="PUT" channel="addUserRequests"/>
</int:header-value-router>
```

Furthermore, I see examples that utilize #requestParams, but the javadoc for 2.1 mentions #queryParameters, and I don't see documentation for either of these in the official documentation page. Do you guys know a good resource that describes not only how SpEL parses expressions but what fields are available to use with it? All I can tell is I have headers, payload, #pathVariables, and maybe #requestParams or #queryParams, along with any other @beans I have defined in the current context.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is always mapped to a header

```
... http_requestMethod=POST ...


Message<?> message = messageBuilder
    .setHeader(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.REQUEST_URL, request.getURI().toString())
    .setHeader(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.REQUEST_METHOD, request.getMethod().toString())
    .setHeader(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.USER_PRINCIPAL, servletRequest.getUserPrincipal())
    .build();
```

The javadoc is wrong. The two additional variables are #requestParams and #pathVariables.

Comment: By the way; please feel free to open up a JIRA issue against the Documentation component, to improve the docs on these variables. https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Mind pointing me to the source file where you found this snippet?

Comment: Sure, it's in HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport; that's also where the variables are added to the SpEL evaluation context evaluationContext.setVariable("requestParams", requestParams);, evaluationContext.setVariable("pathVariables", pathVariables);

Comment: Wow! That source file is waaaay better than any documentation I could find. Thanks! For future reference: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-http/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/http/inbound/HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java